# How to get the desktop path in WinRT?

Tags: winrt-xaml

i was done same thing in WPF by using the below code:

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

But in WinRT Environment doest not have reference GetFolderPath.How could i achive  same thing in WinRT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the blow sample code

StorageFolder testFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    );

also there is more information about special folders in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Comment: hello thanks but i have already specified GetFolderPath and SpecialFolders are not in WinRt.Is there any other way?

Comment: take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464959.aspx

Comment: There is no way to access the desktop path in the blog . there is only how to read and write data  and some other stuffs such as filepicker and folderpicker

Answer (score 0):

Windows Runtime apps don't have access to arbitrary locations in the file system. They can directly access their own data and can get access to well [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) such as the Pictures and Music libraries.

They don't have access to the desktop unless the user has granted it explicitly via a file or folder picker.